# Database selection for soft matching queries

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I am trying to choose a database (preferrably mongodb) that can execute the following query:

Say there is are objects in the database with an array of items:

```
Obj {
    items: [a, b, c, d, e, f]
},
Obj {
    items: [d, e, f, g, h, i]
},
Obj {
    items: [a, z]
},
Obj {
    items: [x, y, z]
}
```

And I want to do a soft search for the objects with the most matching items to a search array, eg.

```
searchArray = [a, b, c, g, i]
```

would ideally return me the first three elements in decreasing order (As there are 3 matched array items in the first element, 2 in the second, and 1 in the third), as you can imagine as the collection grows large it will be important to only return the maximum matched elements.

Is there any way to implement this kind of query in mongodb or any relational databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get that with `$setIntersection`.

- $match items with the query array using $in so you only consider documents with at least one match
- $setIntersect the query array with each items field, and count the number of elements in the intersection
- $sort by the number of matches

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {items: {$in: ["a","b","c","g","i"]}}},
  {$set: {
      matched: {
        $size: {
          $setIntersection: [
            ["a","b","c","g","i"],
            "$items"
          ]
        }
      }
  }},
  {$sort:{matched:-1}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w76Jex1-Iv5)

Comment: Nice answer, I think you should add $limit as well as OP want to limit the no when match items increases